# I'm not understanding who the closeButton proprieties works in React Bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add a modal to my webapp using React Bootstrap Modal and I'm strugling to understand the proprieties closeButton of the `<Modal.Header>`, here's how i've setup my modal

```
<Modal show={this.state.show}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Aggiungi un conto corrente</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body></Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary">
            Annulla
        </Button>
        <Button varian="primary">
            Salva
        </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

the show state is setted to false in the constructor

```
this.state = {
    show: false
}
```

this is all part of a class and I show the modal using this method

```
    showModalAdd(){
        this.setState({
            show: true
        })
    }
```

I'm really strugling to understand what to do, I would really appricieate if you would be so kind to point me in the right direction.

I've tryied to implement a methodd `handleClose` as in the doc but that was in a function situation, I'm implementing it with a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**closeButton** is a  boolean value that Specifies whether the `ModalHeader Component should contain a close button` or not  . When clicking this button, it will `fire an onHide function in the modal component` .

`<Modal.Header closeButton>`  ***=====>*** will add a close button to the model header

`<Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>` ***=====>*** clicking the above button will fire onHide function

**this a demo how it works using  your code   :**

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
  handleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  }
  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Aggiungi un conto corrente</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body> kjkjqskjqjkkjqkjksqkj</Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary">Annulla</Button>
            <Button varian="primary">Salva</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
        <button type="text" onClick={this.handleShow}>
          {" "}
          open modal
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```